# Trying to get certain autocomplete options to fill a textbox with if else statements

Tags: android, autocomplete

Hello I'm new here and i was wondering if it was possible to have an autocomplete textviews list be dictated by another autocomplete textview using if else statements. Here's my code:

```
public class StudentDetail extends ActionBarActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

Button btnSave ,  btnDelete;
Button btnClose;
AutoCompleteTextView editTextName;
AutoCompleteTextView editTextEmail;
AutoCompleteTextView editTextAge;
String[] Names = {"Keenan", "Emily", "Fred"};
String[] Kemails = {"Keenan@email.com", "Knan@email.com", "K-nan@email.com"};
String[] Eemails = {"emily@email.com", "emily1@email.com", "e-m1y@email.com"};
String[] Femails = {"fred@email.com", "freddy@email.com", "fred30@email.com"};
private int _Student_Id=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    editTextName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextEmail = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextAge = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    _Student_Id =0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _Student_Id =intent.getIntExtra("student_Id", 0);
    StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);
    Student student = new Student();
    student = repo.getStudentById(_Student_Id);

    editTextAge.setText(String.valueOf(student.age));
    editTextName.setText(student.name);
    editTextEmail.setText(student.email);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Names);

    editTextName.setThreshold(0);
    editTextName.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (editTextName.toString()=="Keenan"){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Kemails);

        editTextEmail.setThreshold(0);
        editTextEmail.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
    else if(editTextName.toString()=="Emily"){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Eemails);

        editTextEmail.setThreshold(0);
        editTextEmail.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
    else if (editTextName.toString()=="Fred"){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Femails);

        editTextEmail.setThreshold(0);
        editTextEmail.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

}
```

Thank you for reading and taking the time to help :)

Comment: I suppose you hard coded names and emails just for testing purpose. You should give us a little more information on how you would store your names and your emails associated with it and how you plan to retrieve this information. This will help us to give you the best solution depending on your needs. I also noticed that you choose the email depending on the person's name. What would happen if two people have the same name?

Comment: i still have to make the program itself, i just wanted to get through this hurdle first, this is actually an old program im using because the actual system will be similar. The names would be stored in a database created in android studio as well. for the actual system, it wont really matter whether multiple copies of the same data is stored so its fine.